# uniform convergence and uniform cauchy counterexample

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone provide me with an example of a sequence of functions such that ${f_n}$ is uniformly cauchy but not uniformly convergent. Presumably the codomain of the functions cannot be a complete metric space

Answer (score 1):

Just take any sequence $\{x_n\}$ which is Cauchy, but not convergent and take $f_n (x)=x_n$ for all x.